# Code blocks debugger does not display class attributes when in member function

Tags: c++, debugging, codeblocks

I am trying to use Code::Blocks debugger, and I'd like to have access to the values of the class attributes when debugging one of its methods.

I know that when I used Visual Studio, I could unfold the argument "this" to see all the values of the class attributes.

[image]

Do you know if this is possible with Code::Blocks ? Or is there a workaround ?
I don't see myself debugging with Code::Blocks without this feature.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually put *this in the watches ( although I don't expect this kind of workaround to be the right final answer )

[image]